# Unable to pass value from input to fromData in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, fetch, react-hook-form

I am having a form using `react-hook-form` and I am updating the input forms using setState but when I am get `formData` and do a fetch request the value from the input text field is not loading at all.

This is the picture when I update the input text field from `setState` and do a fetch request
[image]

This is the picture when I update the input text field from the keyboard and do a fetch request
[image]

```js
const FirstProject = () => {
  const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState("");
  const [solventstate, setSolventState] = useState("");
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState("");
  const [Error, setError] = useState(null);

  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      solute: "",
      solvent: "",
    },
  });

  const formData = new FormData();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    formData.set("solute", data.solute);
    formData.set("solvent", data.solvent);

    fetch("https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict", {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setFetchData(result.result.predictions);
        //console.log(result.result.predictions);
        //console.log(Object.entries(result));
        // setIsPending(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(data);
        setError(err.error);
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
 <input
  {...register("solute")}
  placeholder="First Name"
  onChange={(e) => setSoluteState(e.target.value)}
  value={solutestate}
 />
 <input
  {...register("solvent")}
  placeholder="First Name"
  onChange={(e) => setSolventState(e.target.value)}
  value={solventstate}
 />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you have to use FormData()? And, is your endpoint expecting JSON data?

Comment: @JBS I am using `react-hook-form` npm module so I need to use FormData() I guess. Yes it is expecting a object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple of issues I can currently see in the code.The state was the same for the `onchange event` for both a `solvent` and `solute` that why they kept using the same state. You needed to use the other hook you created. The 2nd issue you had was that you were sending the variable FormData instead of data (argument provided to function). The form data was an empty variable the whole time. Here is the correct version.

Fixed below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-tdd-0zs4c?file=/src/App.js

```
//per the documents handle submit also gives you the Event Object*

handleSubmit: 
((data: Object, e?: Event) => void, (errors: Object, e?: Event) => void) => Function
```

So your code should be gettin g the input data from the `state/event` object `on change`, and when the user submits, trigger the logic to validate and send.

```js
import Editortwo from "./components/Editortwo";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState();
  const [solventstate, setSolventState] = useState();

  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState("");
  const [Error, setError] = useState(null);

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      solute: "",
      solvent: ""
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = async data => {
    let res;
    console.log(" Post Data To send to API", data);
    try {
      res = await fetch("https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict", {
        method: "post",
        //this was formData which was blank
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res = err;
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    }

    if (!res) {
      console.warn("Invalid Response", res.status);
      throw Error("No API Response");
    }

    const json = await res.json();
    console.log("Results from Request", json);
    if (json.result) {
      setFetchData(json.result.predictions);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Editor {...{ setSoluteState }} />
      <Editortwo {...{ setSolventState }} />
      <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-x-4">
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded  py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          {...register("solute")}
          placeholder="SOLUTE"
          onChange={(e) => setSoluteState(e.target.value)}
          value={solutestate}
        />
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded  py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          {...register("solvent")}
          placeholder="SOLVENT"
          onChange={(e) => setSolventState(e.target.value)}
          value={solventstate}
        />
        <input
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          type="submit"
        />
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded  py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          type="text"
          readOnly
          value={fetchData}
          name="OUTPUT"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error now ```Line 47:19:   'err' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 48:16:   'err' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 310:60:  'e' is not defined    no-undef```

Comment: I am getting error  'e' is not defined  in `onSubmit` also @Josh

Comment: oh remove the Event in the submit handler. it provides it automatically per the documents. I was just trying to show if when you submitted how to prevent that page from refreshing and losing the data. Also if you have this code in codesandbox, repl and share it.

Comment: Errors solved but the code is working like previously. whenever the input fields are updated using state. when I press submit the data is an empty array, but if I type or copy paste into the input fields its working perfectly fine.

Comment: state change on the input fields value is just displayed. but not reflected in data when I do a fetch post request

Comment: @harsh if you put this up on repl.it or codesandbox I would be happy to look at it for you. On the fetch request you have to take the `state` data and verify/check then send it to the API. if thats what you want to do.  When you do the submit you need to prevent the default if your values are going away.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-pond-ojqk0?file=/src/App.js This is the codesandbox link. The state is updated from the two editors. draw a molecule and the molecular formula is reflected in the input text field, when you press submit you will get a floating point.

Comment: Problem is the state is reflecting in input text box but it is not their in data when I do fetch request. but when I simply copy paste the same thing in text box it is working

Comment: can we remove react-hook forms and achieve what I am asking.

Comment: @harsh you had a few bugs in your code. The first one was the state was the same for the onchange event for both a `solvent` and `solute` that why they kept using the same state.  You needed to use the other hook you created like I did in the above. The 2nd issue you had was that you were sending the variable FormData instead of data (argument provided to function). The formdata was an empty variable the whole time. Here is the correct version. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-tdd-0zs4c?file=/src/App.js